# XSSFCell Style seems to be slow

Tags: java, apache-poi, xssf

I'm currently using apache POI to automatically tranfers data from xls file to xlsm file after some process. I have strong executing time constraint and the setters on XSSFCellStyle is very time consuming.

In fact i have files with thousands of cell to transfert and method on boder (SetBorder & SetBorder color) take 3 ms to 5 ms to execution each on 1 cell. In my context 1300 thousands it takes 30 sec to execute.

In a graph on JProfiler, we can see the most time spend on these methods is in state "waiting".

Is it normal for you or not ?

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: not normal. we would need to see your code. But in general when I used POI, I tried to make styles as modular as possible(OOP). set up classes that have a complete cell style rather than just determining it via a decision structure.

Comment: Cell Styles live at the workbook level, and should be re-used between cells that share the same style. Make sure you're only creating one cell style per unique style of cell, and not one per cell!

Comment: thanks, i need to rework my algorithm I think

Answer (score 0):

in for example `org.apache.poi.xssf.model.StylesTable.putStyle( XSSFCellStyle )` they try to find the **`xfs`** twice.

It uses an `ArrayList`.

The more cells, the slower this operation is.

If you can, **try to avoid a lot of dates**.